# Unable to move to cache, unable to move cache folder, unable to create cache

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, caching

I am using VS code to open my react projects. Neither the folder from the git repository nor the locally stowed projects are accessible.

```
[13512:1219/213241.168:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: Zugriff verweigert (0x5)
[13512:1219/213241.169:ERROR:cache_util.cc(145)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\magsu\AppData\Roaming\Code\Cache\Cache_Data to C:\Users\magsu\AppData\Roaming\Code\Cache\old_Cache_Data_000
[13512:1219/213241.169:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(196)] Unable to create cache
```

I tried to reboot, cleaned and emptied the cache, deinstalled and reinstalled VS code.

Comment: What do you need to do exactly?

Comment: I am building a website with react, when typing npm start I get the Errors

Comment: Did you try to restart the windows ?

Comment: Yes I opened and closed many times. Tried several folders, the error comes up with any project.

Comment: You mean, evenif you move the project folder, the issue comes up?

Comment: Yes, if I move the folder or open folders of projects in another drive

Comment: Hi DreamBold, that is quite an offer. But since my hardware is owned by my company I cannot consent to this, sorry.

Comment: @magsunny -  Can you post the command which is executed by npm start?

Comment: Hello Daniel. after npm start: Unable to move the cache: Zugriff verweigert (0x5);Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\magsu\AppData\Roaming\Code\Cache\Cache_Data to C:\Users\magsu\AppData\Roaming\Code\Cache\old_Cache_Data_000;Unable to create cache

Answer (score 5):

I have experienced the same error message with node and python applications. In my case the issue was that I have executed the script file without the language prefix. Instead of:

```
node myscript.js
python myscript.py
```

I have executed:

```
myscript.js
myscript.py
```

I hope that this answer helps anyone having the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Either the permissions are bad or some process is holding a lock on those files (more likely).

I'm guessing in the background you have some process open that uses these files. For example, a dev server. Try killing all `node` processes via Windows Task Manager if you can't find the window and then try again.

Comment: thank you adsy - I tried the Task Manager, but didn't find any node processes. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could there be some other process holding a lock on this? I would try and close all your IDEs/editors as well.

Comment: Hi adsy. I am seeing quite a high rate of mispellings from your account. You might be aware posts here are edited & improved by volunteers, and it would help them (us) out an awful lot of if you could install an English spell-checker. Thanks!